# Multiple work book paste crashing at 3+ files

Tags: excel, vba

The below code works fine when I ask it to add the information from the first two files with approximately 200 rows, however if i add a third it crashes Excel. I need this code to combine upward of 40 files each time it is run by the user.

I had originally written the file to use selects and found a post here saying that it could slow down or cause crash and rewrote it to this current iteration removing all selects from the program.

```
Public Sub ImportUpdates()
Dim ImportXL        As Workbook
Dim OpenFiles()     As Variant
Dim i               As Long
Dim r               As Long
Dim n               As Long
Dim Crntwrkbk       As String
Dim Crng            As Range
Dim Cloc            As Long



'Application.ScreenUpdating = False


Crntwrkbk = ThisWorkbook.Name


OpenFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
Title:="Select File(s) To Import", _
MultiSelect:=True)

n = Application.CountA(OpenFiles)

For i = 1 To n
        Set ImportXL = Workbooks.Open(OpenFiles(i))

        ImportXL.Worksheets("Entries").Activate
        r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Crng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(r, 2))

        Crng.Copy

        Windows(Crntwrkbk).Activate
        Worksheets("Entries").Activate

        Cloc = Workbooks(Crntwrkbk).Worksheets("Entries").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        Worksheets("Entries").Range("A" & Cloc).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        ImportXL.Close True

Next i


'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Workbooks(Crntwrkbk).Activate

End Sub
```

Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: When you use `.Activate` and `.Select` you are just asking for a debugging nightmare. Learn to avoid it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Before your loop `debug.print UBound(OpenFiles)` and `debug.print n`, what are your results?

Comment: Kdavis mentioned activate, is there a way to remove it here

Comment: Yes, read the link he provided.

Comment: Not sure how i did not mentally process the link. the immediate window using debug is showing the number from n for number of files when i use the debug above

Comment: @jwb2j and you're sure `UBound(OpenFiles)` equals `n`? I am guessing that they're not and that's why your loop is crashing.

Comment: i worked out how to take the activates out of the code and it now works like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but looks correct to me (though this might eb a good learning exercise for you to figure out if it isnt working correctly).

Its a way to use arrays, dynamic ranges and late binding to move data around. Plus its a good exercise/refresher in some parts of the excel object model.

Happy coding!

```
Public Sub ImportUpdates()
    Dim ImportXL As Workbook
    Dim OpenFiles() As Variant
    Dim pickUp as Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, iXLRowC As Long, iXLColC As Long, cWbkRowC As LONG, cWbkColC As Long
    Dim Crntwrkbk As String
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Crntwrkbk = ThisWorkbook.Name
    OpenFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select File(s) To Import", MultiSelect:=True)
    n = Application.CountA(OpenFiles)
    For i = 1 To n
        Set ImportXL = Workbooks.Open(OpenFiles(i))
        With ImportXL
            iXLRowC = .WorkSheets("Entries").UsedRange.Rows.Count
            iXLColC = .WorkSheets("Entries").UsedRange.Columns.Count
            pickUp = .WorkSheets("Entries").Range(.WorkSheets("Entries").Cells(2,1), .WorkSheets("Entries").Cells(iXLRowC, iXLColC)).Value
        End with
        With Crntwrkbk
            cWbkRowC = .WorkSheets("Entries").UsedRange.Rows.Count
            cWbkColC = .WorkSheets("Entries").UsedRange.Columns.Count
            .Worksheets("Entries").Range(.Worksheets("Entries").Cells(cWbkRowC+1, .Worksheets("Entries").Cells(cWbkColC+1), _
                .WorkSheets("Entries").Cells(cWbkRowC+1+iXLRowC, cWbkColC+1+iXLColC))).Value2 = pickUp
        End with
        Erase pickUp
        ImportXL.Close True
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```